# how to make 2 calls from sipp to mobile based on sip

Tags: sip

I need to make two calls from sipp to mobile. I have just read that sipp's multi-udp socket mode will make it possible. If anybody knows how to use this functionality, please tell me the commands. Please give any more information you have on this... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that, unless your server has a source IP:port security check per SIP URI, you should be able to establish two different calls by using only one port. In order to achieve this, you would need to work with a csv file containing different used entities, I suggest you to check [this](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/reference.html#inffile) documentation.

Just to try to help a bit more on this, I think, the scenario you're looking for is a bit like [the branchc example](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/branchc.xml.html). In order to use is with two different users, you will need to have a csv file like:

```
SEQUENTIAL
user1
user2
```

and replace all `ua1` references by `[field0]`, for example:

```
<send retrans="500">
   <![CDATA[

   REGISTER sip:CA.cym.com SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
   From: ua1 <sip:ua1@nnl.cym:[local_port]>;tag=[call_number]
   To: ua1 <sip:ua1@nnl.cym:[local_port]>
   Call-ID: [call_id]
   CSeq: 1 REGISTER
   Contact: sip:ua1@[local_ip]:[local_port]
   Content-Length: 0
   Expires: 300

   ]]>
</send>
```

Would become:

```
<send retrans="500">
   <![CDATA[

   REGISTER sip:CA.cym.com SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/[transport] [local_ip]:[local_port];branch=[branch]
   From: [field0] <sip:[field0]@nnl.cym:[local_port]>;tag=[call_number]
   To: [field0] <sip:[field0]@nnl.cym:[local_port]>
   Call-ID: [call_id]
   CSeq: 1 REGISTER
   Contact: sip:[filed0]@[local_ip]:[local_port]
   Content-Length: 0
   Expires: 300

   ]]>
</send>
```

and, when you call `sipp` reference `csv` file by adding: `-inf <CSV_FILE>.csv -infindex <CSV_FILE>.csv 0`

And, if you still wants to use different ports, all this is still valid, you would only need to add `-t un` to `sipp` call.

Hope this helps